# Nodemailer - Why does my contact form randomly send a message of "undefined undefined undefined" from undefined?

Tags: javascript, nodemailer, contact-form

I have set up a contact form for my portfolio website, it works great and I have had a few friends send me emails using it. It has four input fields, first name, last name, email, and  body for the message. However, every once in a while I get an email sent from my account "Message from undefined" and the other three input fields are all undefined as well. The input fields are required, so it cannot be a blank message being submitted. [Message from contact form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6efu.png). Sorry if this has been asked before, I googled it and looked on a few posts but could not find anything. I am just curious as to why this happens. Also, I did use a gmail account and Oauth2 authentication.

This is the HTML for the contact form:

```html
 <form action="#" class="row contact-form">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-3"><input type="text" placeholder="First Name"
                                id="inputFirstName" class="shadow form-control form-control-lg" required></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-3"><input type="text" placeholder="Last Name"
                                id="inputLastName" class="shadow form-control form-control-lg" required></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3"><input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" id="inputEmail"
                                class="shadow form-control form-control-lg" required></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="8"
                                class="shadow form-control form-control-lg" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center d-grid mt-1">
                          
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill pt-3 pb-3">
                                Send Message
                                <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
                        </button> 
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

This is how my server is set up for nodemailer

```js
   //Oauth Variables
const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
  process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground"
);

oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
});

const accessToken = oauth2Client.getAccessToken();

//Contact Form
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  //Nodemailer Transporter
    const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      type: "OAuth2",
      user: process.env.EMAIL,
      accessToken: accessToken,
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      refreshToken: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
    },
  });
// Nodemailer options
  let mailOptions = {
    from: req.body.email,
    to: process.env.EMAIL,
    subject: `Message from ${req.body.email}`,
    text: `${req.body.nameFirst}  ${req.body.nameLast} \n  ${req.body.message}`,
  };
//Nodemailer Transporter/Sendmail
  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      res.send("error");
    } else {
      res.send("success");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you have some code you can share?

Comment: Also note that the image you shared reveals you're Yahoo address. You may or may not care about that.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I added some code and uploaded a different screen shot.

Comment: Maybe a bot is submitting the form incorrectly or empty, or someone is submitting the form who uses an old browser not supporting `required`, or maybe someone manually removed the `required`, or maybe someone is playing around with your site trying to hack it, or or or... You shouldn't try to send an email if the fields are undefined. `required` is only for user convenience, like any client-side validation is; you always have to do the same validation also on your server! (If you want to get to the bottom of this, log the full raw request headers+body and user IP when you encounter this.)

Comment: Do you read this article and try to follow step by step - https://nodemailer.com/about/

Answer (score 0):

So I use d`nodemailer` a while ago and your code is quite different to mine. While it might be a case of a changed interface this might be worth a shot:

```
const email = new Email({
            message: {
                from: "some-bot@gmail.com",
            },
            preview: false,
            transport: this._transport,
            render: async () => html,
        });

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            email.send({
                text: html,
                message: {
                    to: user.email,
                    subject: "Email Subject",
                },
            })
            .then(resolve)
            .catch(reject);
        });
```

I create an actual Email object which is used to send the email.